# Format string and date using perl

Tags: perl

I would like to convert (using perl)

`05\/26\/2013 06:09:47`  to `26-05-2013 06:09:47`

Also how can i change the above to GMT date and time?

Comment: Have you browsed the CPAN at all? Plenty of good stuff there.

Comment: [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) has sections on Date, Time and DateTime handling.  The [`POSIX`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module has `strftime()`; the (non-core) [`POSIX::strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX%3A%3Astrptime) module has `strptime()`.  Do you really have backslash and slash in the data?  Are you sure you don't want `2013-05-26 06:09:47` as the output?  And for this specific transform, you could easily write a regex.

Comment: NB: To convert the time to GMT, you have to know which time zone it is presented in.  Or are you thinking about a 'Unix timestamp', the number of seconds since 'The Epoch' or 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $src_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%m\\/%d\\/%Y %H:%M:%S',
   time_zone => 'local',   # or America/New_York
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dst_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',
);

my $dt = $src_format->parse_datetime('05\\/26\\/2013 06:09:47');
$dt->set_time_zone('GMT');
say $dst_format->format_datetime($dt);
```

---

If we're specifically dealing with local and UTC/GMT, then the following is lighter, though perhaps a bit more cryptic.

```
use POSIX       qw( strftime );
use Time::Local qw( timelocal );

my ($m,$d,$Y, $H,$M,$S) =
      '05\\/26\\/2013 06:09:47' =~
         m{^(\d+)\\/(\d+)\\/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\z}
   or die;
say strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', gmtime(timelocal($S,$M,$H, $d,$m-1,$Y-1900)));
```

Comment: Someone pointed out you might want unix/epoch time rather than the time in GMT. `$dt->epoch` and `timelocal($S,$M,$H, $d,$m-1,$Y-1900)` will give unix/epoch time.

Comment: I just realized that i cannot install perl modules due to some reasons.

So i cannot use DateTime. And i'm not dealing with localtime. I need to convert GMT -7 to GMT.  Any help please.