# Convert date format and timezone using Perl

Tags: perl

How can i convert:

`05\/26\/2013 06:09:47` to `25 May 2013 23:09:47`

The above date is in GMT-7 time zone.
How can i change it to GMT time in the above format.

Thanks.

Comment: What was wrong with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954166/format-string-and-date-using-perl) answer?

Comment: @squiguy this is for a different requirement. the date format changed and now will need to convert gmt-7 to gmt

Comment: @ikegami  Yes, it should be 26 May 2013 06:09:47  now

Comment: You seem to think SO is a code writing service. Have you even tried to do this for yourself?

Comment: @chrsblck yes but i'm not able to figure out how to convert gmt-7 to gmt.

Comment: @ikegami I provided both times in GMT-7. After this formatting, i want to convert this to GMT.

Comment: @ikegami Question edit. Thanks!

Comment: @ikegami  It is GMT-7.  That is the problem actually. Thanks!

Comment: oh right. No DST right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $src_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%m\\/%d\\/%Y %H:%M:%S',
   time_zone => '+0700',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dst_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
   locale    => 'en_US',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $src_format->parse_datetime('05\\/26\\/2013 06:09:47');
$dt->set_time_zone('GMT');
say $dst_format->format_datetime($dt);
```

Comment: One question, is this efficient? I need to run this for 10000 entries like this at once

Comment: There are surely faster ways. But determine which way is faster (not to mention any time spent coding and testing) would take longer than actually processing the 10,000 entries.